# (JQUERY) check if input A OR input B has value

Tags: jquery, validation, if-statement, input

I'm trying to check if 1 of 2 inputs has a value as an IF statement. Here is the [html](/questions/tagged/html):

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <label>Width</label>
        <input type=text id="value1" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Height</label>
        <input type=text id="value2" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to check whether `input#value1` OR `input#value2` has a value...

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($("#value2").val() != "" || $("#value1").val() != ""){
 //code here
}
```

a bit sophisticated way, unless you want accept `0` as a value.

```
var val1 = $("#value1").val();
var val2 = $("#value2").val();

 if (val1 || val2){
     //code here
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($("#value1").val()!="" || $("#value2").val()!="") {
    // do something
}
```